# Always runs service in background on Android?

Tags: android, service, background

I am building an app which has a background service for continuously communicating with a Raspberry Pi.

I am making the service sticky(Service.START_STICKY) so that is will restart when it's killed by user or OS.

This works well for the first 30-40 minuten. After 30-40 minutes the services seems to be stopped.

Isn't there any way to avoid this problem? I know it's bad for the batterylife if there is service continiously runnnig in the background. The app is used in my own project to automate my room and is only used by me. So the batterylife isn't a problem.

```
public class RaspberryPiCommunication extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //Do continuouswork here in a seperate thread
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

I also have another quetions about service:
If the service is started twice in the following example, will there be two instances of SomeObject() and is doSomWork() running twice in background?

```
public class RaspberryPiCommunication extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
        obj.doSomeWork();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the service on its own thread ? By default, A service runs on the main thread. For a long running task like this run it in a separate thread

```
Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to do that work.
```

Service will run only in one Instance. onStartCommand() is called every time you start the service.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#StartingAService

Comment: Yes i'm executing the code in a seperate thread. But i'm having an issue with this. I'm using BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback to search for Bluetooth Low Energy devices. The callback is always executed on the main thread, doesn't matter if i start it in a seperate thread. You're saying that there will be only one instance of Service running, no matter if you start it multiple times. Does this mean that the service is restarted when starting it a second time? And does it mean that all the objects are erased from memory and recreated in onstartcommand?

Comment: In your case ,    obj.doSomeWork();  will be called everytime you call startService() . The service is stopped when you call Context.stopService or stopself. All the objects would be erased only when the service is stopped . As you are creating an object in OnStartCommand() , it will be created multiple times. You can avoid calling startService multiple times by making a check if the service is in a running state.

Answer (score 0):

Here is required piece of code.

```
    @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000 );// 1000 - Milliseconds
    if (appContext == null) {
         appContext = getBaseContext();
        }
    Toast.makeText(appContext, "Services Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return START_STICKY;
}

Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            DoBackgroundTasks();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000 ); // 1000 - Milliseconds


    }
 };
 void DoBackgroundTasks()
    {
       //write code here.
    }
```

Comment: create context object in your service public static Context appContext = null;

Comment: How is this solving my problem? The Runnable and handler doesn't exist anymore is the service is killed by the OS. Maby AlarManager would be the solution here. Just restart service every 30 minutes with alarmManager.

Comment: Who told you ??. These are not even deprecated.Try to use that , I am using this piece of code in my apps. @user3494179

Comment: and BTW In such situations it is good programming practice to use a thread with service. @user3494179

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest where you have declared your service, add this

```
android:process="remote"
```

Comment: What effect does this have?

Comment: the service will run in another process.

Comment: And the other process won't be killed by the OS after some time?

Comment: less likely to be killed. there is no such thing on Android OS that will run forever, it will get eventually killed and you need to restart it.

Comment: How does whatsapp work? Isn't the whatsapp app constantly running in background to receive messages and notify user?

Comment: It does not aleays run. It is killed and reatarted when needed or by time based intents - RTC alarm. All services on android can be killed, if you make your service a forground runner, it will have min. chance to be killed.